# What is the point of splitting up a project into 2 separate projects?

Tags: java

A lot of times I see people splitting up a Project into 2 separate projects, like in this screenshot:

[image]

What is the point of seperating Ingot and IngotAPI instead of putting them both in the same project because they get compiled together anyways?

Comment: maybe you can distribute them separately, if some other project needs only one of them for example

Comment: [Increasing modularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming). Without knowing anything about this specific project, Core and API modules usually have distinct functionality. Perhaps this question may be better suited for [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: This is so NOT an opinion based question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several cases.

Need or desire to have API **decoupled** from (one of) its implementation. With the **Java SPI** (Service Provider Interface) you provide just an interface, against which client application program. Then the java SPI provides a lookup to use one of the possible implementations. Used for the XML parser. Similar for JDBC. Decoupling an API means that a client need not be recompiled if the API remains unchanged, but the implementation was changed.

In general having several projects allows to consider every project a **module**, a unit that imports a specified list of other modules, and forms a layered hierarchy. This can give a software system much higher quality, no back and forth imports. Next generation java will get modules.

Answer (score 1):

One reason for doing this is that an implementation can be interchangeable.

Imagine a situation where you have two clients who use your application. Both of them have different requirement for a how to do a thing(e.g. algorithm is different) but a type of a result is the same. In this case client code should work directly only with API and doesn't dependent on any implementation. During a build you can specify which implementation should be used.

With this solution:

- if any new client arrives you will easily create an implementation for new requirement without changing API or a client code. It makes your old code more reusable.
- you don't have to rebuild API or a client if changes has been made only in an implementation. It saves developers time during work.
- during tests you can provide an implementation with mock-ups for some parts of business logic

Answer (score 0):

First To made code more re-usable. By packaging in different project different functionality it's easier to find the functionality that you want to carry over to another project (in that case you could export the entire IngotAPI to a new project).
Second for testing. It's much easier to keep under control testing result when each project has it's own unit test separated, and than a test that check the integration between the two project.

For example, if the IngotAPI is well developed, it shouldn't have any dependencies toward Ingot project. That means that if you make any change on Ingot project, you don't need to Test IngotAPI independently, since it will not be affected (high cohesion), you'll just need to test Ingot, and the where ingot use IngotAPI.

Answer (score 0):

IngotAPI seems to be something that should be easy to refer to from other projects.
Maybe it will be used in the future somewhere else.

In the end it doesn't really matter as you can also just copy your classes from other projects into the recent one.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that when you implement an API you want to distribute it to the potential clients. By dividing in two (or more) projects, you can distribute only the interfaces and business objects, and keep the implementation for yourself.

In that way, you don't have to redistribute on any implementation change.